# PDFBox | Crash on line: PDDocument.load(file)

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, loading, pdfbox

I have the following simplified code:

```
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
PDDocument doc;
String text = "";

try {
    File textFile = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/PDF-test.txt");
    doc = PDDocument.load(textFile);
    text = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
} finally {
   ...
}

...

PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

content.setFont(font, 12);

content.beginText();
// Write to page using a text file
content.showText(text);
content.endText();
content.close();
```

---

**The Problem**

I get the following error: `java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line` on the line:

`doc = PDDocument.load(textFile);` in the `try` block.

---

**What I've Tried**

I've tried these solutions but none have worked:

- [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument does not load / read the PDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888775/org-apache-pdfbox-pdmodel-pddocument-does-not-load-read-the-pdf-document)
- [How to extract text from a PDF file with Apache PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813727/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-with-apache-pdfbox)
- https://www.javatpoint.com/pdfbox-reading-text
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4443
- [merge files gives error: End-of-File, expected line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871270/merge-files-gives-error-end-of-file-expected-line)
- [PDFBox IOException: End of File, expected line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953924/pdfbox-ioexception-end-of-file-expected-line)

---

**Expected Results**

I want to load the text file without error and display it as a PDF with PDFBox.

Comment: What do you want to do? PDDocument.load expects a pdf file, not a txt file. See javadoc https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(java.io.File)

Comment: @TomStroemer Well well, thanks for that. I was under the assumption that it could load text files. Fixing now...

Comment: @TomStroemer It worked! Thank you! Please add that as an answer to my question and I will give you the rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDDocument.load expects a pdf file, not a txt file.

See javadoc of PDDocument: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(java.io.File)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and time. Have yourself a good day!

Comment: Hi @TomStroemer,  I am using `pdf` file, not  text file I'm getting this type exception. system can't execute this line `PDDocument.load(file)`

My code:

`String pdfDir = tempPdfDir + File.separatorChar + "mypdf.pdf"
                        File file = new File("${pdfDir}")
                        pd = PDDocument.load(file)  // this line can't execute.`


error: `java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line`

Comment: Use new File(pdfDir) instead of new File("${pdfDir}"). Check if the File exists, before you call the function. (file.exists()). Please create a separate issue if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

In PDFBox 3.0, you have to use `org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(new File(...))`

For more information, check https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html